# ADF Run pipeline 24 times within a 24 hour period each month

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline, that triggers each month. Then it has to be triggered 24 times each hour within 24 hour period and then wait for the next monthly run. I've managed to do this using ForEach activity with @range(1,24) and Notebook activity with Python code that checks time.

But I'm wondering is there any way to do this without Python, using built-in ADF features.

Comment: Have you looked into scheduled pipeline triggers? I suspect this will help you solve your scheduling challenge.

Comment: We use Logic Apps to manage most scheduling tasks. Lots of flexibility around recurrence patterns, and you can always capture the current date/time and do branching logic to run a pipeline.